# Realm: Field Map inside another Map as RealmObject

Tags: android, realm

I need to parse json incoming from external system.
Here json example:

```
{
    "address": "My address",
    "contacts": "My contacts",
    "exchangeRatesMap": {
        "CHF": {
            "field1": "7.103",
            "field2": "11.003"

        },
        "EUR": {
            "field1": "90.123",
            "field2": "1.003"
        },
        "USD": {
            "field1": "0.103",
            "field2": "20.123"

        }
    },
    "name": "Name of organization",
    "id": 1
}
```

As result I create Java POJO (not Realm) in my Android application:

```
public class ExchangeRate {
    private int id;
        private String name;
        private String address;
        private String contacts;
        private Map<String, Map<String, String>> exchangeRatesMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

    }
```

And its work fine. OK.

And now I need to migrate Java POJO to Realm Object.

Question:
How object **ExchangeRates** will be look as **RealmObject**?

Comment: Are the countries well-defined or dynamic? As in, do the countries change from time to time? Also, do you need to query them somehow?

Comment: I edit my post. Number of countries are dynamically. Tomorrow can add new e.g "AUS". But fields of countries are always  2 (field1, field2). Query (example): on organization with Id=1 get all fields of country "USD".Result will be 0.103 and 20.123.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm doesn't support maps yet (see https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/759), but you can convert it into a List by hand by doing something like this:

```
public class ExchangeRateItem extends RealmObject {
    public String key;
    public double field1;
    public double field2;
```

}

```
public class ExchangeRate {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String contacts;
    private RealmList<ExchangeRateItem> exchangeRates;
}
```

You will need to find a way to convert the ExchangeRate blocks to one object though. How will depend on what kind of JSON deserializer you use or if you use the JSON directly.